# Explode to break line after every other comma

Tags: php, regex, explode

I am trying to insert break line after every other comma when I echo my $model varible which consists of list of many different models for each product which is pulled out from mysql database. I am trying to do it with `explode`, but am failing, because it only shows the first row of 2 (model1, model2). Other models from the list are missing. What I have so far is:

```
   <?php 
$commasCount = count(explode(',', $model));
if ($commasCount > 2) {
    $model = preg_replace('~,[^,]*,~', "\$0\n", $model);

}
echo $model;
 ?>
```

My question is - How do I show the full list of models two by two in a row and not just the first two records? Thank you.

Comment: have you checked what is hold inside $commasCount ? Maybe then you will see what you should change

Comment: Maybe `$model = preg_replace('~,[^,]*,~', "\$0\n", $model)` will do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding

> I am trying to insert break line after every other comma

You may use a `preg_replace` with the following regex:

```
$model = preg_replace('~,[^,]*,~', "\$0\n", $model);
```

or - if you render the output in a Web browser:

```
$model = preg_replace('~,[^,]*,~', "\$0<br/>", $model);
```

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qrOdQW/2).

Basically, matching comma, 0+ symbols other than comma (with `[^,]*`), and again a comma, and then replacing the matched text with itself (`$0`) adding a line break.

Comment: When I do that, they get back to regular view, I can see them all, but they are not two by two in a row.
My code is now:

<?php 
$commasCount = count(explode(',', $model));
if ($commasCount > 2) {
    $model = preg_replace('~,[^,]*,~', "\$0\n", $model);
    
}
echo $model;
 ?>

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: @Nancy: I guess you want `<br>` instead of `\n`, don't you?

Comment: @Toto, yes, but how do I achieve this at all?

Comment: @Nancy: replace `"\$0\n"` with `"\$0<br/>"`. That will work if you render the text inside a Web browser.

Comment: @Wiktor, I saw the demo, but when I implement in my code, it doesn't work. I will update my code now in original question.

Comment: Wiktor and @Toto, thank you, guys, it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_chunk` to group items two by two:

```
$models = array_chunk(explode(',', $model), 2);
$pairs = array_map(function ($i) {
    return implode(',', $i);
}, $models);
$result = implode(",\n", $pairs);
```